# I want to write a trigger on opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

My question is: given I have an Opportunity, and there are no open mandatory sales tasks associated to it, when I try and change the opportunity stage then this shall be allowed by the system.

Given I have an aviation Opportunity, and there are open mandatory.

I tried this one and i don't know weather it is right or wrong. so, please help me for this scenario.

```
trigger Opportunity_Task on Opportunity (before update) {
    List<Task> ts =new List<Task> ();
    List<Opportunity> op =new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id,Opportunity> oldMap = trigger.oldMap;
    Map<Id,Opportunity> newMap = trigger.newMap;
    List<id> optyid = new List<id>();
    for(id opid:oldMap.keySet()) {
        Opportunity op =new Opportunity();
        if(oldMap.get(opid).tasks == null && op.stageName=='Closed Won') {
            op.addError('You can create a new task for that Opportunity');
            task t = new task();
            t.WhatId=opid;
            t.Description='kjdkfhsdkf';
            t.Status='open';
            ts.add(t);
        }
        else{
            if(oldMap.get(opid).tasks!=null && op.StageName=='Closed Won')
            op.addError('You cannot modify the opportunity status');

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete. More specifically, you never fully describe your second scenario. Please [edit] your question to make your description of your problem complete. About the only thing that I can tell you right now is that your trigger won't work as you intend it to because `oldMap.get(opid).tasks` will be either `null` or an empty list. Data on parent (or child) records are not available in trigger context variables and must be explicitly queried.

Comment: Your Opportunity related lists aren't populated in trigger context. You'd perform a query to locate them. But your logic also doesn't make any sense - with `addError()`, you're actually just blocking all Opportunity updates from being committed.

Answer (score 6):

What you're saying and what your code is saying is pretty different:

### What you say you want

If there are open tasks, do not allow editing of the opportunity

```
Trigger OpportunityTrigger (before update) {
    // Since triggers do not have access to child records you'll have to query them
    // I like doing it as a subequery as it saves you from needing to map them out
    // yourself. Make sure to only include the tasks that you DO NOT
    // want to see.
    List<Opportunity> oppsWithTasks = new List<Opportunity>([
        SELECT Id, (
            SELECT Id
            FROM Tasks
            WHERE Status != 'Complete'
        )
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New
    ]);

    // Loop the the opps
    for (Opportunity opp : oppsWithTasks) {
        // If the query returns any tasks, you know this is an opp that should
        // not be changed.
        if (!opp.tasks.IsEmpty()) {
            // Add the error to the trigger object, not the object you queried
            // If you use opp.addError, nothing will happen.
            Trigger.NewMap.get(opp.Id).addError('Opp has open tasks');
        }
    }
}
```

### What your code says you want

When an opp is closed, automatically create a task

```
List<Task> tasksToInsert = new List<Task>();

for (Opportunity opp : trigger.New) {
    // Make sure that the status is correct
    // Make sure that the update only occurs when the status is changed
    // Otherwise, you'll end up with too many tasks
    if (
        opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' && 
        opp.StageName != trigger.oldmap.get(opp.Id).StageName
    ) {
        // I prefer to initialize sobjects like this as it uses fewer
        // characters in code (and there is a character limit in apex)
        tasksToInsert.add(new Task(
            WhatId = opp.Id,
            Description = '',
            Status = ''
        ));
    }
}

// Check to see if there are any tasks before calling insert
if (!tasksToInsert.isEmpty()) {
    insert tasksToInsert;
}
```

### Put together:

```
Trigger OpportunityTrigger (before update) {
    List<Task> tasksToInsert = new List<Task>();
    List<Opportunity> oppsWithTasks = new List<Opportunity>([
        SELECT Id, (
            SELECT Id
            FROM Tasks
            WHERE Status != 'Complete'
        )
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New
    ]);

    for (Opportunity opp : oppsWithTasks) {
        if (!opp.tasks.IsEmpty()) {
            Trigger.NewMap.get(opp.Id).addError('Opp has open tasks');
        }
    }

    for (Opportunity opp : trigger.New) {
        if (
            opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' &&
            opp.StageName != trigger.oldmap.get(opp.Id).StageName
        ) {
            tasksToInsert.add(new Task(
                WhatId = opp.Id,
                Description = '',
                Status = ''
            ));
        }
    }

    if (!tasksToInsert.isEmpty()) {
        insert tasksToInsert;
    }
}
```

### Extra Tips (I'm bored)

It's best practice to create a utility class to hold most of the functionality of the trigger.

```
public class OpportunityUtils {
    public static void validateMandatoryTasksClosed(Map<Id, Opportunity> updatedOpps) {
        List<Opportunity> oppsWithTasks = new List<Opportunity>([
            SELECT Id, (
                SELECT Id
                FROM Tasks
                WHERE Status != 'Complete'
            )
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE Id IN :updatedOpps.keySet()
        ]);

        for (Opportunity opp : oppsWithTasks) {
            if (!opp.tasks.IsEmpty()) {
                updatedOpps.get(opp.Id).addError('Opp has open tasks');
            }
        }
    }

    public static void autoCreateFollowUpTask(List<Opportunity> newOpps, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOpps) {
        List<Task> tasksToInsert = new List<Task>();

        for (Opportunity newOpp : newOpps) {
            // Expanded to support insert triggers
            // Using oldOpps == null tells you if it's insert or not
            // This means that if an opp is inserted as a closed won the
            // task still gets created
            if (
                newOpp.StageName == 'Closed Won' && (
                    oldOpps == null ||
                    newOpp.StageName != oldOpps.get(newOpp.Id).StageName
                )
            ) {
                tasksToInsert.add(new Task(
                    WhatId = opp.Id,
                    Description = '',
                    Status = ''
                ));
            }
        }

        if (!tasksToInsert.isEmpty()) {
            insert tasksToInsert;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your trigger looks like this:

```
// Added a support for after update/after insert
Trigger OpportunityTrigger (before update, after update, after insert) {
    if (Trigger.IsBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        OpportunityUtils.validateMandatoryTasksClosed(Trigger.newMap());
    } else if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        // Handle creating tasks in after trigger, not before trigger
        OpportunityUtils.autoCreateFollowUpTask(Trigger.New, Trigger.OldMap);
    }
}
```

### New Switch feature for APEX

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/summer18-rethink-trigger-logic-with-apex-switch.html)

```
Trigger OpportunityTrigger (before update, after update, after insert) {
    switch on triggerEvent {
        when BEFORE_UPDATE {
            OpportunityUtils.validateMandatoryTasksClosed(Trigger.newMap());
        }

        when AFTER_INSERT, AFTER_UPDATE {
            OpportunityUtils.autoCreateFollowUpTask(Trigger.New, Trigger.OldMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, good ole' boredom tips. One thing to note is that with the release of Summer '18, the new switch statement + the new `Trigger.operationType` context variable can quite nicely replace the old if/else checks using things like `Trigger.isBefore` and `Trigger.isUpdate`. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/summer18-rethink-trigger-logic-with-apex-switch.html

Comment: Updated the answer to include a switch example. I will note that I did not see just an "AFTER" enumeration. I also don't feel this is any more/less readable. I do however, like that triggerEvent allows for passing a single parameter to a helper method which could help curve tricks like my `oldMap == null` that I use specifically to avoid passing in the `trigger.isX` to my methods. The more I look at it the more I like the old way, more control (for now).